# Itk level tracing image filter

Tags: image-processing, filter, itk

Someone knows how the ***itk::LevelTracingImageFilter*** works?

I found only the header file, with no explanation https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/blob/main/Libs/vtkITK/itkLevelTracingImageFilter.h

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'd go ask on the Slicer disourse, discourse.slicer.org.